# Ford applink sync error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, smartdevicelink

I am currently working on the ford applink sync SDK for iOS and I have downloaded the Applink Emulator (ALE) v 1.0.2 and v 2.4 and trying to run the sample application installed in iPhone 6 with it. After doing the settings for the ApplinkTester app in device settings to match with the Tcp/ip settings specified for the app AND starting the ALE emulator on mac.

I do get the connection response to be "true" but when I run any command on the ALE it either gets "rejected" or "aborted".
Is there something I am missing. kindly please help me as I am stuck in this from over a week.

sample app link : https://developer.ford.com/content/restricted/hello_sdl_ios.zip

ALE help : https://developer.ford.com/content/restricted/ALE_v2.4_User_Guide(EN).pdf

ALE download link : https://developer.ford.com/content/restricted/ALE_MAC_2.4.zip

LOG:
 iphone6 with ale v1.0.2:
in the log i get the connectivity success but when I send any command it gts either rejected or aborted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

AppLink dev here. Hopefully we can get this sorted out on here.

Do you see the app show up in ALE when you connect over TCP/IP?

One thing to note about Applink is that certain RPCs (commands) require a certain HMI level. When the app first connects to ALE, it issues a Register App Interface (or RAI), that lets ALE know what the app is called, what it's app id is, and what VR commands to register to listen for. This can be done on HMI level of none or higher. When you actually select the application (by highlighting it in ALE, and then hitting `OK`, you should see in the logs that the HMI level changes from `NONE`, to `FULL`, and then RPCs are sent (which in this case are a Show, Speak, and AddCommand RPC). If you look at the code for the hello_sdl_ios portion, a place to look at would be `onOnHMIStatus:(SDLOnHMIStatus *)notification`.

Here's a link to what I'm referring to: [Hello_SDL_iOS's onOnHMIStatus:](https://github.com/smartdevicelink/hello_sdl_ios/blob/b3fbb0a42dd7fc7a37ff710c9c1cb4c0a5c9c7eb/HelloSDL/HelloSDL/HSDLProxyManager.m#L185)

Comment: Hello Alex, thanks for answering. I have downloaded the code that you provided and it contains pod file configuration. Is there any way you can provide me or guide me to use the non pod version of the code. Thanks.

Comment: I am using the applinktest application for testing and in that the RAI works I see the green log info.

Comment: Are you correctly using TCP/IP? If the RAI is successful, you should be seeing the application show up within ALE.

Comment: Thanks Alex, yes the RAI was successfull and I also saw the json response in Green color, while all other requests are in red color,

Comment: You should see the application show up on the ALE when there is a successful RAI, without having to press any buttons. Are you sure the application is not showing up?

Comment: Yes, the application is not showing up in the ALE simulator. can you please provide me the screenshot of the ALE simulator where the application is actually shown up, Can you please also tell me is it necessary to use get the Application registered with ford to get it working on the ALE simulator. Thanks.

Comment: Mooez, does this video help you at all? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAPdYCVv79o

Comment: thanks alex for sharing this with me. I am really sorry to say that when I run the HelloSDL sample code the ALE simulator does not detect the new app, Is it possible that you can send me the sample source code and also the ALE simulator, it will be a huge favor for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mooez, I pulled the sample code from the link you provided as well as ALE. Are you sure you are using the IP address of the machine that ALE is running on when you deploy Hello SDL?

Comment: Mooez, if you're still having issues please join us on slack: http://slack.smartdevicelink.com
Here you'll get instant responses to your questions.